# Is there a way to get more information from the maven dependency analysis report?

Tags: java, maven

After implementing a project, I generate a site that includes the maven dependency analysis report. It will tell me which dependencies are used and not declared, unused but declared, etc...

For projects that I didn't write, I sometimes find it challenging to figure out which classes are using individual dependencies. Is there a way to dig in deeper with the dependency analysis report to figure out which classes are using a specific dependency?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Give us an example.  And tell us what technology you're currently using.

Comment: Sure. Let's say I have a maven java project that produces a jar. And let's say the maven dependency analysis report says that I'm using guava, but haven't declared it. I'd like to know specifically which java class uses an object provided by guava.

The specific plugin I'm using is this one: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-report-mojo.html

As you can see on the documentation, it doesn't say anything on how to dig deeper.

Comment: If that's impossible, I wouldn't be surprised.  A class could use reflection to refer to a class in a jar that didn't exist during compile time.  Maven dependencies, on the other hand, have to be defined.  I think that'll be the level of granularity you'll get: Dep A uses Dep B.

Comment: Somehow it "knows" if a dependency is being used or unused. That's the purpose of the report. It is to tell me that I've declared something that I'm not using or that I'm using a resource that was pulled in transitively.

Comment: That's a good point.  But, perhaps "unused and declared" means "defined in `<dependencyManagement>` but not use anywhere in `<dependencies>`"

Comment: No... This plugin does an excellent job at determining what's used/unused. To try it for yourself, take an existing maven project and add an arbitrary dependency that is not used. Then run the site report and you'll see what I mean. I'm confident that this report is accurate, I'm just seeing if anyone on stack overflow knows of a way to get more information from this report either through a separate maven plugin or some other process.